# Javascript sobrescrevendo class css

Tags: javascript, css

Ao usar uma função em javascript em dois selects populados, ele sobrescreve o css ocultando seus valores e atribuindo outra classe, conforme imagens a seguir:

Antes de usar a função:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao clicar no primeiro select e escolher uma opção:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Inspecionando o elemento no navegador:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ele atribuiu o `display: none` e utilizou de outras classes do css para fazer essa bagunça. Ao utilizar css para atribuir `display: visible !important` ele reaparece porém mostra dois selects:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não estou conseguindo resolver:

Havendo necessidade deixo o código javascript aqui!

Código javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".select1").change(function() {
        var proxima_turma = <?php echo json_encode($proxima_turma); ?>;
        var antiga_turma = <?php echo json_encode($antiga_turma); ?>;

        var valor = $(this).val();
        var select = $(this).closest("tr").find(".select2"); // busca o select2 da mesma linha

        if (valor == "") {
            select
            .html("")
            .append("<option value=''> Selecione </option>");

        } else if (valor == "<?php echo $class_id_to;?>") {
            select.html("");

            for(var i = 0; i < proxima_turma.length; ++i) {
                select.append("<option value='" + proxima_turma[i]['section_id'] + "'>" + proxima_turma[i]['name'] + "</option>");
            }                  


        } else if (valor == "<?php echo $class_id_from; ?>") {

            select.html("");

            for(var i = 0; i < antiga_turma.length; ++i) {
                select.append("<option value='" + antiga_turma[i]['section_id'] + "'>" + antiga_turma[i]['name'] + "</option>");
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Código do select:

```
<select <?php if ((($transferidos != null) && ($evadidos != null)) OR (($transferidos != null) || ($evadidos != null))) ?>
class="form-control selectboxit select2" <?php if (!$disableSelect) { ?>
name="promotion_status2_<?php echo $row['student_id'];?>" style="width: 40px;"
<?php } ?> >
<?php if ((($transferidos != null) && ($evadidos != null)) OR (($transferidos 
 != null) || ($evadidos != null))) { ?>
 <option value="null" selected></option>
 <?php }else{ 
?>
<option value="">selecione</option>                             
</select>
```

Comment: Coloca seu javascript também, para sabermos o que ele está fazendo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pela aparência e pela classe `.selectboxit` você está usando um plugin chamado [SelectBoxIt](http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/), e ele possui um método próprio para popular o select adicionando novos options. Se você adicionar options diretamente no select sem chamar o método `.add()` do plugin, não vai fazer nenhum efeito, porque o select original é escondido pelo plugin e criado um pseudo-select customizado no lugar.

Para remover todos os options você usa:

```
select.data("selectBox-selectBoxIt").remove();
```

Para adicionar novos, após o `.append`, você usa:

```
select.data("selectBox-selectBoxIt").add();
```

Seu código irá ficar assim:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".select1").change(function() {
        var proxima_turma = <?php echo json_encode($proxima_turma); ?>;
        var antiga_turma = <?php echo json_encode($antiga_turma); ?>;

        var valor = $(this).val();
        var select = $(this).closest("tr").find(".select2"); // busca o select2 da mesma linha

         var box = select.data("selectBox-selectBoxIt");
         box.remove();

        if (valor == "") {
            select.append("<option value=''> Selecione </option>");
        } else if (valor == "<?php echo $class_id_to;?>") {
            for(var i = 0; i < proxima_turma.length; ++i) {
                select.append("<option value='" + proxima_turma[i]['section_id'] + "'>" + proxima_turma[i]['name'] + "</option>");
            }                  
        } else if (valor == "<?php echo $class_id_from; ?>") {
            for(var i = 0; i < antiga_turma.length; ++i) {
                select.append("<option value='" + antiga_turma[i]['section_id'] + "'>" + antiga_turma[i]['name'] + "</option>");
            }
        }

        box.add();
    });

});
```

Veja em funcionamento:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

   $(".select2").selectBoxIt();

    $(".select1").change(function() {
        var proxima_turma = [{"section_id": 11, "name": "Maneta"},{"section_id": 12, "name": "Baqueta"}];
        var antiga_turma = [{"section_id": 13, "name": "Guimeta"},{"section_id": 14, "name": "Fusqueta"}];

        var valor = $(this).val();
        var select = $(this).closest("tr").find(".select2"); // busca o select2 da mesma linha

         var box = select.data("selectBox-selectBoxIt");
         box.remove();

        if (valor == "") {
            select
            .append("<option value=''> Selecione </option>");

        } else if (valor == 1) {

            for(var i = 0; i < proxima_turma.length; ++i) {
                select.append("<option value='" + proxima_turma[i]['section_id'] + "'>" + proxima_turma[i]['name'] + "</option>");
            }                  


        } else if (valor == 2) {


            for(var i = 0; i < antiga_turma.length; ++i) {
                select.append("<option value='" + antiga_turma[i]['section_id'] + "'>" + antiga_turma[i]['name'] + "</option>");
            }
        }
        
        box.add();
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/css/jquery.selectBoxIt.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.selectboxit/3.8.0/jquery.selectBoxIt.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <td>
         <select class="select1">
            <option value="">Selecione...</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
         </select>
      </td>
      <td>
         <select class="form-control selectboxit select2">
            <option value=''> Selecione </option>
         </select>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <select class="select1">
            <option value="">Selecione...</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
         </select>
      </td>
      <td>
         <select class="form-control selectboxit select2">
            <option value=''> Selecione </option>
         </select>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```